# Javascript code: I want the text box to be empty when on focus

Tags: javascript

I want the text dissappear when the username box is clicked, am I doing it right with onfocus? what am I doing wrong, please help.

```js
 document.getElementById("username").onfocus = function() {
   document.getElementById("username").value = "";
 }
```

```html
<form name="Sign Up">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><i><b>Siqn Up</b></i>
    </legend>
    <p>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" value="Unique ID" name="username">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: How about using a **placeholder**? Instead of value="username", it would be placeholder="username". And you wouldn't need any JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box only has a `name` of `"username"`. You need to give it an `id` attribute as well.

```
<input type="text" value="Unique ID" name="username" id="username">
```

Notice how the javascript function is called getElementBy**Id**? :) That means it needs an Id!

Comment: Thanks dude very much.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than changing the `value` directly (kind of hacky and prone to complications), use the `placeholder` attribute. It's made for doing exactly this - no javascript required.

```html
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Unique ID">
```

Comment: awesome dude, from where did you get that thing!

Comment: `placeholder` got added to the HTML spec a while ago - you can read some very thorough docs here if you're curious! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 1):

You are using getElementById and passing "name" attribute as an argument, which will never be found, so use getElementsByName:

```
 document.getElementsByName("username")[0].onfocus=function()
 document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value = "";
```

Comment: Thanks mate very much.